# Attribute "imageAspectRatioAdjust" already defined with incompatible format.(APT0000)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, release

My game is able to build and run on debug mode so I was hoping it would be ready to be built in release mode but I'm currently stuck with this error in the title. Anyone knows the solution?

**EDIT** : I've tried commenting the imageAspectRatioAdjust in common_attrs.xml but it would cause alot more different errors.

**EDIT** : I've found out that there is two file that contains imageAspectRatioAdjust in the release folder of my game when I tried to build it, but there is only 1 file that contains imageAspectRationAdjust in debug. Even if I tried to delete one or the other, I have to clean and rebuild and it would reappear again in the same folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added Facebook Android SDK into a sub project which a main project is dependant on, which requires me to add Facebook Android SDK into the main project as well but I've accidentally updated some of the packages in the component on the main project and did not update the packages on the sub project, which seems to be the cause of this error.